# Raw transaction structure

Tags: raw-transaction, ethereumjs-tx

I made two raw transactions. One was generated by [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/master/docs/index.md), the other by [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#offline-transaction). They are identical until about the last seventh of the way through. Is there a way to work out what caused the differences?

```
0xf9012a058504e3b2920083061a809427b277e71004fd629b4b5f23ce9cedde0df6fae980b8c4e3d2923153746576650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003334323533333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006823dd004334474d4146384438425775446532484800000000000000000000000000000057686f6c6520636f6d70616e7900000000000000000000000000000000000000307832393334303030613361366330323238336665316537396363623830303326a031e4a61cdbf1a802ba9176e35083ed0ed8593fd130e32f0f650919653177a516a0416d5c3d315e26e4db24226b0ab6927315150185404c133a5097fcf2a9aaa527

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
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try using the "unsign()" function in the [ethereumjs-tx-sign](https://github.com/warren-bank/ethereumjs-tx-sign) library to inspect all the data contained in each of your raw transaction values.. and compare the contents.

You may find that it comes down to fixing an oversight in properly encoding all of the input parameters used when generating the raw transaction. A missing '0x' can wreak havoc.

Comment: I believe this is wrong. The raw transactions only differ on the signature part and the signatures are non-deterministic, so the transactions are supposed to be non-deterministic and thus different every time you create a new signed raw transaction even with the same inputs and using the same program.

Comment: The unsign() function will reveal that the data in the two raw transactions are the same except for the signature parts.

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a lot going on here so bear with me.

Your raw transactions include a signature and signatures are non-deterministic, meaning that they contain a random element. This is the reason for the raw transactions being different. They only differ on the signature part. If you create a signed raw transactions twice for the same private key, input and using the same program, you should also get two different outputs.

To see why and how they differ, you must first know how raw transactions are encoded. A transaction is the RLP-encoding of these fields:

```
RLP(T_n, T_p, T_g, T_t, T_v, T_d, T_w, T_r, T_s)
```

RLP is a way of encoding an arbitrary datastructure into a byte array specified in [Ethereum Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io/), Appendix B.

The last three elements specify a point on an ECDSA curve. This point has been generated by the signing algorithm and the signing algorithm takes a random number when performing the signature. If this random number was not used, it would be possible to derive the private key from the signatures.

The two raw transactions differ only in the `T_w`, `T_r`, and `T_s` fields.

For the first transaction, the last three fields are:

```
26 [T_w]

a0 [length indication of T_r]
31e4a61cdbf1a802ba9176e35083ed0ed8593fd130e32f0f650919653177a516 [T_r]

a0 [length indication of T_s]
416d5c3d315e26e4db24226b0ab6927315150185404c133a5097fcf2a9aaa527 [T_s]
```

For the second transaction, the last three fields are:

```
1c [T_w]

a0 [length indication of T_r]
beb2c5b5fa47345a4df29e02d1fb746b59357fa21b44a4766994731229cb107d [T_r]

a0 [length indication of T_s]
2fd57c9e32d253ae86982dbcc66c30b5108d9b4ecb76eb84c92c55a3c889f5f8 [T_s]
```

That being said, the `T_w` values indicate that two different signing schemes have been used here. The  `T_w=0x1c` is the original signature scheme whereas the `T_w=0x26` is the [EIP 155 signature scheme](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md). Both signature schemes are valid and will be accepted on the Ethereum blockchain. EIP 155 was invented to protect against replay attacks and it is a newer way of signing an Ethereum transaction.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

another possible cause (that was just [reported](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/issues/74)) is that there may be in issue with the output generated by `ethereumjs-tx` when a `chainId` is specified. TBD..

Comment: The chainid did seem to be involved. I fixed the issue by removing the 1 from `var tx = new Transaction(null, 1)` and declaring later by `tx.chanId = 1`

Comment: `chainId` is stored by `tx` as an internal value: `tx._chainId`.. it sounds like you didn't assign a value and it defaulted to the pre-EIP 155 behavior.. which is effectively assigning `{chainID: 0}`. The EIP 155 [spec](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/155#issuecomment-318205104) itself seems a little unclear on exactly how `r` and `s` should be encoded. Waiting for some clarification.. as right now `ethereumjs-tx` is setting the values to zero-length Buffers.. which seems wrong.. but the example (output) and some of the discussion implies that the RLP encoded values are correct.

Comment: PPS) the [`Transaction() constructor`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/dab647f12775118bd5b235797e73715ec4ddd5e7/index.js#L47) only accepts a single parameter.. `chainId` wouldn't be passed as an integer to a 2nd parameter.. it would be included in the hash table passed in the first.

Comment: oops.. I'd never used (or looked at) "MyEtherWallet" prior to just now. Does it even support a `chainId` field? Quick look.. but I don't see that as an input field.. so maybe the tool is pre- EIP 155.. which makes sense that its output would only match `ethereumjs-tx` when no `chainId` is specified.

Answer (score 0):

“Creating offline/raw transactions with Go-Ethereum” @akshay_111meher https://medium.com/@akshay_111meher/creating-offline-raw-transactions-with-go-ethereum-8d6cc8174c5d

This is something off-track for your questions. However, you can clearly get transaction structure in this blog